# Left property in MXML - Flex 4 SDK

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mxml, flashdevelop

Why does the following button not line up 100px from the left edge?

```
<mx:Button left="100"></mx:Button>
```

I am using the Flex 4(Gumbo) SDK, I am pretty sure that if you try to do it in FlashBuilder, it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using absolute or relative layout?

```
<mx:Application Layout="absolute">
```

And if trying either of those doesn't work... I don't think I've ever seen someone use "left" (I'm sure it works, but it looks odd to me). Try changing "left" to "x":

```
<mx:Button x="100" />
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.

I agree that using it for left is odd, but it is practicle for a resizable application, when using left, right, top, bottom.

Comment: Remember... It works, but it depends if that's how you want ALL the components to act. If you have controls within a panel of canvas, all controls will be placed according to the absolute value, rather than relative to the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have it nested in some other component.

In this example button will be placed 200px left (100px for panel + 100px button for button left attribute)

```
<s:Panel x="100" y="100" width="250" height="200">
    <mx:Button left="100"></mx:Button>
</s:Panel>
```

Comment: nested? Could you please explain, It is the only component in the application so far.

Comment: This is my entire application:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" >
 <mx:Panel x="100" y="100" width="250" height="200">
  <mx:Button left="100"></mx:Button>
 </mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>

This is my output file:
http://sitoon.com/labs/isoperior.swf

Comment: I assume nested is asking if you happen to have the component inside a "Canvas" or something similar. If you are on a relative layout, or using relative layout for that specific control, then it will be 100 away from the canvas, rather than the side of the window.

Comment: You have the button embedded in a panel. It's relative to the Panel's position. Change it to absolute, or make it "0" relative to the panel.